# Multiple MQTT/ AWS shadow services on one device

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, mqtt, aws-iot

Would it be considered bad design to have multiple MQTT / AWS services on one device. I am currently designing a system that has what can be considered multiple discrete functions / process's.

I am intending to have each process use it's own AWS named shadow's to sync settings and data. Each process will have its own client ID so no issues there and data use isn't an issue how ever the internet connection my not always be reliable.

Is there any major draw backs to this approach?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a single connection and use different MQTT topics and shadows for each discrete function? Part of IOT Core billing is based on minutes per connection. Multiple MQTT sessions on one device multiplies the cost. I would just embed the client ID in the topic and then you can easily isolate the data with the rules engine.

Comment: True, i hadn't considered the billing implications of multiple connections, it does sound like a v2 improvement :-)